# Редактирование вложенных ресурсов в rails; как найти объект по id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1) При использовании ссылки "Edit" поля в edit.html.erb заполняются атрибутами первого объекта(task) среди созданных. Так будто бы используется метод .first а не метод .find(id)
Нужно, соответственно, чтобы редактировался всегда тот объект у которого вызван edit

пробовал изменить в TasksController

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@task = @project.tasks.find_by(project_id: params[:id])
```

так:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
```

получаю ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#edit (Couldn't find Task with 'id')

пробовал менять `<%= form_for  [@project, @task] do |f| %>` на `<%= form_for @task do |f| %>` получаю NoMethodError in Tasks#edit (undefined method `task_path')

наконец менял link в show.html.erb Были и другие попытки, но всё в тех же местах.

2) Если всё-таки нажать Update Task, получаю NoMethodError in TasksController#update (undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass) в строке

`@task.update(task_params)`

Ошибка где-то в указании пути к нужному объекту?

Вот исходники:

TasksController

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find_by(project_id: params[:id])
end

def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
end

def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find_by(project_id: params[:id])

    @task.update(task_params)
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
end

def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
end

private
def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :status)
end

end
```

edit.html.erb

```
    <h2>Add a task:</h2>

    <%= form_for  [@project, @task] do |f| %>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </p>
      ...
      <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'welcome/index'

      resources :projects do
        resources :tasks
      end

      root 'welcome#index'
    end
```

projects/show.html.erb

```
...
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy task', [task.project, task],
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                 |
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_task_path(@project) %> 
  </p>

...
```

routes

```
    welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                       welcome#index
    project_tasks GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#index
                  POST   /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#create
 new_project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks/new(.:format)      tasks#new
edit_project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
     project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#show
                  PATCH  /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
                  PUT    /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
                  DELETE /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#destroy
         projects GET    /projects(.:format)                            projects#index
                  POST   /projects(.:format)                            projects#create
      new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                        projects#new
     edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                   projects#edit
          project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#show
                  PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                  PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                  DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#destroy
             root GET    /                                              welcome#index
```

Заранее спасибо.

Duplicate in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44999912/6794200

Comment: У вас эпохальный беспорядок в коде. С чего б начать... `@project.tasks` это уже что-то вроде `Task.where(project_id: params[:id])`. И ваше `@project.tasks.find_by(project_id: params[:id])` ищет таски, у которых `project_id` равен сразу и `params[:id]` и `params[:project_id]`. **Не странно?** Дальше.  `edit_project_task_path(@project)`. Почему в параметрах нет таска, на который вы хотите ссылку? Как, по-вашему, Rails должен догадаться? :) Берите отладчик, разбирайтесь по порядку, на каком этапе вы получаете в параметрах неожиданные значения и потому неожиданные результаты. Волшебства не бывает.

Comment: В контроллере таска в самом начале всё сделал верно: не использовал  `find_by`, было `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])` и `@task = Task.find(params[:id])`. Но после последовал ряд ошибок (это в первую очередь было связано с тем, что я плохо понимал, как между собой взаимодействуют контроллер, вью и модель) считал, что ошибку совершил где-то в контроллере, начал пробовать разные варианты.. а результат Вы видели. Оказалось корень проблемы был в ссылке, да, я не указал в параметрах таск. Но про пустил это. Здесь, Ваш комментарий был очень кстати, оказался очень полезным. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это пример того, как были исправлены ошибки. Спасибо всем за помощь.

*Если ответ и окажется кому-то полезным, то только таким же новичкам как и я. Возможно, вам будет проще воспринимать этот код если вы замените здесь projects на articles, а tasks на comments.*

1) Была неверно указана ссылка на action, в параметра не было таска, верный вариант, может выглядеть так:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit task', [:edit, task.project, task] %>
```

2) После, вот как следовало искать нужным мне task:

```
  def edit
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Вот, как выглядит окончательный вариант такс контроллера:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
  end

  def create
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)

      redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end

  def update
      @task.update_attributes!(task_params)

      redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end

  def destroy
      @task.destroy

      redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end

  private
  def set_task
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :status)
  end
end
```

3) Нужно не забыть про верное создание формы:

```
<%= form_for  [@project, @task] do |f| %>
```